# blogdown rss feed broken, links don't have domain name

Tags: r, blogdown, feedburner

I set up a blogdown site following instructions from https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/ repository on Github, deployed via Netlify, using the XMin theme. After setting it up I updated the rss feed details on feedburner to the xml file from the blogdown site.

Feedburner sends posts via email to subscribers, and today I found out that the link in the email to the specific post is missing the domain. So, instead of pointing to example.com/post/2018/11/12/post-title/ it directs to /post/2018/11/12/post-title/. Clicking on it gives the message:  invalid URL.

Has anyone had similar issues? I don't know how/where to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right.

I had a misformatted baseURL in config.toml.